# Data persistence in a table Layout

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-tablelayout

How can I save a variable that is passed from an activity to a table layout  in another Activity using  Shared preferences, for example, a list of items and it's prices

**1. Dread Lock Loosen 0.70**

**2. Dread Lock Removing 0.45**

I want to make these data persist or to be saved even if I close the app

Comment: these are key-value pairs so [sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example) will be a good option

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you,

// Good way to use shared preference is like this

public class AppSharedPreference {

public static final String ABC_APP_SHARED_PREFERENCES = "com.example.bachatgatapp.sharedpreferences"; ///////Agent Details need to store in shared preferences///////

private static final String MOBILE_FILE = "mobfile";

// SET - GET "MOBILE NUMBER" IN SHARED PREFERENCE

public static void setMobileFile(Context context, String value) 
{ 
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(ABC_APP_SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

preferences.edit().putString(MOBILE_FILE, value).commit();
 }

public static String getMobileFile(Context context) {

SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(ABC_APP_SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

return preferences.getString(MOBILE_FILE, "");
 }

// Write this code to save value in shared preference

AppSharedPreference.setMobileFile(this, mobile_number);

Comment: Sir please assuming i am having a table layout consisting of rows , how will these code save my values passed to it ,so that when i close the app my values will still be present in my table layout . @user6318595